# How do I add a javascript object to an existing javascript object?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

```
var old = { 'a':3, 'b': 5 }
var new = { 'a': 999, 'c': 10 }
```

how do I append the "new" to the "old" and result in:

```
{ 'a': 999, 'b': 5, 'c': 10 }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using a framework most have a function that will do it, e.g jQuery's extend. Otherwise if you're using JavaScript with no framework you'd have to do it yourself.

You could do it using a for...in loop.

```
for(var key in newObject)
{
    if(!newObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         continue;
    }
    oldObject[key] = newObject[key];
}
```

As a side note don't call vars "new" its a keyword in more than a few languages. Np if its just for the example. I've renamed it in my example from new to newObject upon suggestions from the comments.

Psts right, needed to check in the for...in loop the var was actually new's

Comment: +1 for remembering `hasOwnProperty()`, but wouldn't it be simpler to just do the assignment in the `if` instead of continuing when the property isn't found?

Comment: Would indeed be simpler, but it's not a great deal more complex, this way has the added benefit of being easier to extend, e.g. if deep object merge (merge sub-object properties instead of total overwrite) was required.  As it stands though it would read slightly better with the if statement inverted and surrounding the assignment.

Comment: It does indeed come down a good bit to style... I prefer a single flow-approach so would use the inversion of the above. However, the above *will result in syntax errors* because `new` is taken as a reserved word and will keep it from being parsed correctly. Granted it was a poor choice in the initial post -- perhaps consider renaming it and adding a note for future readers :)

Comment: Did include a bit about using new as a variable name wasn't a good idea, thought it best to keep the example closer to his initial example. On mobile site at the moment so will update the code in a bit.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery provide a better function call $.extend.
For example:

```
var old_obj = {'a': 3, 'b': 5};
var new_obj = {'a': 999, 'c': 10};
var result = $.extend(old_obj, new_obj);
```

The result will be

```
{a: 999, b: 5, c: 10}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var o = { 'a':3, 'b': 5 };
var n = { 'a': 999, 'c': 10 };

for (var key in n){
    o[key]=n[key];
}
```

Comment: This should use `hasOwnProperty` to avoid copying over too much. Alternatively, there are already existing functions from a number of libraries to help ... might be worthwhile to mention one or two.

Comment: he wants an override though - so just checking hasOwnProperty is not enough - he should check the value as well